# Dynamic datasource lookup using JPA

Tags: persistence, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I want to bind variable dataSourceString(possible value:HR,FINANCE : i am getting dataSourceString value  dynamically by jsp) to DataSource. When dataSourceString value is HR then connect to TESTDS and when dataSourceString value is FINANCE then connect to TESTDS1.Means based on dataSourceString value i want to connect to datasource.
Enviornment : EJB3,weblogic10.3.3,JPA

Note:One more thing i dont want to write if-else loop in sessionbean like when dataSourceString is HR then connect to this EnityManage else to different EntityManager.currently there are 10-15 possible value of dataSourceString. I want to write code like if in future if a new dataSourceString is added then only i have to change persistence.xml.

After research i came to the following code,But getting some error.

Error:-

```
No persistence unit named 'em' is available in scope test.jar. Available persistence units: [HR, FINANCE]


    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:467)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:507)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:149)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

      Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit named 'em' is available in scope test.jar. Available persistence units: [HR, FINANCE]
    at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.getPersistenceUnit(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:132)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:38)
    at weblogic.deployment.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.<init>(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:35)
    at weblogic.deployment.BaseEnvironmentBuilder.createPersistenceContextProxy(BaseEnvironmentBuilder.java:974)
    at weblogic.deployment.BaseEnvironmentBuilder.addPersistenceContextRefs(BaseEnvironmentBuilder.java:855)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Error is obvious that there is no persistence unit for em is available in persistence.xml
But how can i achieve lookup of datasource using jpa dynamically.
Following is my code

Session Bean

```
package entity.library;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.*;

@Remote(TestInterface.class)
@Stateless(mappedName="ejb3/TestBeans")

public class TestSessionBean implements Serializable, TestInterface 
{
 protected TestJPA test;
protected Collection <TestJPA> list;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf; 


   public Collection <TestJPA> getAllList(String dataSourceString) {

emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(dataSourceString);
em = emf.createEntityManager(); 

list=em.createQuery("SELECT test FROM TestJPA test").getResultList();
   return list;
  }
  }
```

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="HR" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>TESTDS</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>TESTDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="FINANCE" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>TESTDS1</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>TESTDS1</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is a single persistence unit defined in persistence.xml, then it default unit for application & the same is is injected by annotation.

You can lookup manually the specific persistence context at runtime.

```
 javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager =
                (javax.persistence.EntityManager)initCtx.lookup(
                    "java:comp/env/" + persistenceContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better...

Instead of: 
@PersistenceContext(name="myPU")
private EntityManager em;

specify:

@PeristenceContext(unitName="myPU")
private EntityManager em;